# Error in MySQL Syntax for a Case Statement

Tags: mysql, case

I'm working on a baseball projections system, and I'm trying to have two different formulas based on games started.

This is my current error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ROUND( COALESCE(IP1,0) * .5 + COALESCE(IP2,0) * .1 + 60 ))
>   D( COALESCE(IP1,0) *' at line 6

And this is what my code looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE player_ip_2015
AS 
SELECT playerID
    ,CASE
        WHEN (b.GS > 5)
            THEN (ROUND( COALESCE(IP1,0) * .5 + COALESCE(IP2,0) * .1 + 60 ))
            ELSE (ROUND( COALESCE(IP1,0) * .5 + COALESCE(IP2,0) * .1 + 20 ))
            END
            AS IP
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT playerID FROM pitching_pos) b
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT playerID AS playerID1, (IPOuts/3) AS IP1 FROM pitching_pos
                WHERE yearID = "2014") b1
                ON b.playerID = b1.playerID1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT playerID AS playerID2, (IPOuts/3) AS IP2 FROM pitching_pos
                WHERE yearID = "2013") b2
                ON b.playerID = b2.playerID2) b
GROUP BY playerID
ORDER BY IP DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a `(` before `Case` and you're never closing it
you should remove the `(` anyway (or close it after `End`

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of IP1?
Secondly, your title to the question does not match the error you are reporting.
Thirdly, you also have an extra ( in the FROM section of the statement.

Check your code.

Comment: Sorry for the comment, I see many answers include questions to the OP. I edited my submission. The question was prematurely submitted without checking syntax.

Comment: I'm just confused with the syntax right now. IP1 is the value for innings pitched in 2014. Should I maybe include that section in the case statement?

Comment: Best I can offer is to review the docs, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html  you still have not updated the code to show the correct syntax by removing the extra (. You have a number of syntax issues in the post. Fix those first and see how far that gets you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to MySQL and I don't fully understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That is why I provided a link to the documentation. You should also include any error messages getting returned.